# How to update database it is display the message your database updated without any error but actually my data base not update

Tags: java

Please findout the error it display the message your database updated but actually does not happen please give some suggestions ![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEfuy.jpg

Comment: Put the code here. It is unclear what you are asking. Add more information in order to review your question.

Comment: In your SQL UPDATE string, is the table field **ID** actually a **TEXT** data type? Are you sure it's not a **LONG** data type? If it's a LONG data type then you shouldn't use the single quotes for the **ID** value.

Comment: Also, in the future, please **do not** provide your code as a link. Your question may help others that visit SO and when they do there is a very high probability that your link will be dead. **Always** provide your code within your post. Thank you.